# Keep cursor out of all Textboxes on form

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a form with several buttons and TextBoxes. After the user clicks on a button, the text in one or more of the TextBoxes changes, and the cursor (edit: caret, not the mouse cursor) goes into a textbox.  ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681156/text-is-selected-in-the-text-box) helped, identifying that the TextBox with the lowest TabStop as being the one where it would land, and explaining how to avoid having text in that box selected when this happens.) But what I'd like to see is that the cursor (caret) stays out of all the TextBoxes unless the user decides he wants to put it there -- highlight & copy something, for instance.  This wouldn't be common, but it could happen.

How can I make adjustments to the form or the TextBoxes so that the cursor (caret) doesn't show up in *any* textbox (so long as the user doesn't click inside a TextBox)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the code in your button's click event causes the focus to change to another control, you could update the last line of the click event, like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Your code here
    Button1.Focus() 'this last line of the sub sets the focus back to the button
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, it looks like setting the `TabStop` property of each TextBox to `False` will also prevent the cursor from moving into any of the TextBoxes on its own after a Refresh.

I suspect that sBarbacki's answer will work equally well, or probably better with a large number of controls that one wants to avoid getting the focus automatically.

Comment: Can you clarify do you mean the cursor (i. e. the mouse pointer) or the caret?  If you set the TabStop property of the controls to False, you will no longer be able to use the Tab key to move between them.

Comment: The caret - not the mouse cursor.  Good distinction to make, and I should have been more clear. Being unable to tab between the text boxes is entirely acceptable in this application, but that could obviously be a major limitation elsewhere.